# when I need to use @staticmethod and @classmethod in python programming?

Tags: python

I like to know when I need to use `staticmethod` or `classmethod` decorators.
can you please guide me simple code, so that can understand usage of 
`staticmethod` and `classmethod`.

Comment: What about when the function is *static*, or when it is a method attached to a *class*...

Comment: You never really *need* to use `staticmethod` not `classmethod`, although, `classmethod` is actually useful sometimes

Answer (score 1):

When you call a method of a python object, the object itself is automatically passed as the first parameters (usually named `self`)

You can change this in two ways

- annotate with `@classmethod`: now, instead of the object, the *class of the object* is automatically passed as first argument
- annotate with `@staticmethod`: now, no extra argument is passed, just the ones you provided. Just like a normal python function

Classmethods are commonly used for alternative constructors. Static methods are plain functions that are put inside the class namespace, just for logical grouping.